# How do I safely transport a wine bottle in my check-in luggage when flying?

Tags: packaging

In a few days, I will be flying on an airplane.
I was requested by my hosts to bring a bottle of wine.
However, I am worried that if I don't pack my wine bottle in a safe way,
the bottle will crack and spill wine all over my belongings.

**What is the best way to pack my wine bottle into my check-in luggage,
to minimize the chance that it cracks during my journey?**

Answer (score 4):

Put the bottle in a few plastic airtight bags, just in case (could be ordinary shopping bags but check that they are not damaged, and tie them tightly. Discard if they leak air). Then pack your luggage so that the bottle is in the middle and all your clothes are packed around it. Make sure that no hard objects are in contact with the bottle but there is a safe cloth-area in between them instead. Pack your luggage tightly so that there isn't much moving around of your items within the suitcase/rucksack, or otherwise tie your clothes with a string around the bottle.

Answer (score 2):

I carried a beer bottle in my flight, I wrapped the bottle with news papers and cloth and lots of tape. Make sure you cover the edges too, since they can easily crack, and also make sure that no heavy stuff is around your bottle that can crush it. I was able to safely bring home the bottle

If you find a box that can fit, go ahead with that too.